# Check at runtime whether a class is part of the code or part of one of the dependencies

Tags: java, reflection, libraries

I am working on an engine which uses the Java Reflect library to get methods of classes and their super classes. For the analysis, I need to know which of the methods are inherited by a super class, and whether the super class is part of one of the libraries or if the class is part of the project itself. Is there any way to determine this?

I tried to use the classloader, but I either don't know which is the correct way of doing so or it doesn't work (what I rather think), cause the classloader can also load classes of the dependency.

Furthermore, it can be the case that a project has many modules as well as packages, which makes it (in my opportunity, but maybe I'm wrong) impossible to use the package, which the class is part of.

Comment: What is a library or project to you? If you can’t name a technical artifact that maps to a library or project without ambiguity, we can’t do it for you, especially after you ruled out the straight-forward candidates (packages, modules, etc) already.

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide your problem into several distinct steps:

- What is the parent class for one class?
- Where is some class loaded from?
- Is the source a class is loaded from the main module?

### What is the parent class for one class?

On any instance you can use the [.getClass()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) method, or you can reference something like String.class in your code directly.

Once you have the class, run [getSuperclass()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass()) to find the parent.
Note that this does not care about implemented interfaces.

### Where is some class loaded from?

On every of the Classes you obtained by traversing the inheritance tree, you can run [getClassloader()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader()). Depending on the classloader itself you could obtain even more information.

Also the [getPackage()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getPackage()) information will give you some information about the class. However it is possible to split packages across different jar files and class loaders, which makes detection a bit tricky.

A very powerful solution is to obtain the URL where a class was loaded from. For that ask the class (or the classloader) for a URL to that class, like so:

```
Class clazz = ... (some class in question)
URL location = clazz.getResource('/' + clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class");
```

With that you will receive urls like

```
jar:file:/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/lang/Object.class
```

### Is the source a class is loaded from the main module?

Now it all boils down to comparing URL strings. Just look at the part before the exclamation mark and you should have a jar file. The answer should get quite easy now.

Comment: For top level classes, the `clazz.getResource('/' + clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class")` can be simplified to `clazz.getResource(clazz.getSimpleName() + ".class")`. But since Java 9, the result for `Object.class` et al will be something like `jrt:/java.base/java/lang/Object.class`.

Comment: Hmm. That may mean we have to distinguish Java9+ or modular applications.
Would the URLs there still be comparable? Feel free to update my answer.